# in Object.keys(obj) works only part time

Tags: javascript

Im trying to look if a number is in the Object.keys() for some reason I get a partial response some of the numbers are not included in the final object. Any idea why `in` works only partially here?

```js
var arrayOfNumbersIHave = [
  "542009988",
  "7411111111",
  "542261111",
  "542009988",
  "7411111111",
  "7411111111",
  "7442334675",
  "661766029",
  "692549335",
]

var snapObject = {
  "542009988": "A",
  "542261111": "B",
  "661766029": "C",
  "6617666029": "D",
  "692549335": "E",
  "7442334675": "F",
  "7411111111": "G",
}

var objToDisplay = {};

for (const i in arrayOfNumbersIHave) {
  if (i in Object.keys(snapObject)) {
    objToDisplay[arrayOfNumbersIHave[i]] = snapObject[arrayOfNumbersIHave[i]]

  }
}

console.log(objToDisplay)
```

**Result:**

```
{
  "542009988": "A",
  "542261111": "B",
  "7442334675": "F",
  "7411111111": "G",
}
```

**Expected result:**

```
{
  "542009988": "A",
  "542261111": "B",
  "661766029": "C",
  "692549335": "E",
  "7442334675": "F",
  "7411111111": "G",
}
```

Comment: In your code, `i` is the *index*, not the value. Do a `console.log(i)` and you'll see `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, etc, whereas it sounds like you're expecting `"542009988"`, `"7411111111"`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can avoid using `for..in` to iterate an array. Alternatively you can use `reduce` on the  `arrayOfNumbersIHave` & in each iteration `curr` parameter will represent each element of  `arrayOfNumbersIHave`. Use this `curr` to check if there exist a key by same name in  `snapObject`. Is so then in the accumulator object add the key and value

```js
let arrayOfNumbersIHave = [
  "542009988",
  "7411111111",
  "542261111",
  "542009988",
  "7411111111",
  "7411111111",
  "7442334675",
  "661766029",
  "692549335",
]

let snapObject = {
  "542009988": "A",
  "542261111": "B",
  "661766029": "C",
  "6617666029": "D",
  "692549335": "E",
  "7442334675": "F",
  "7411111111": "G",
}

let objToDisplay = arrayOfNumbersIHave.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  if (snapObject[curr]) {
    acc[curr] = snapObject[curr]
  }
  return acc;
}, {}) // {} is accumulator object 

console.log(objToDisplay)
```

Answer (score 4):

Using the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) in that manner is not quite correct.  `in` checks for either *properties in objects* or ***indices** in an array*.  So it is probably returning `true` only when the number you are checking happens to be an index in the array.

So for this case, you really want to omit the `Object.keys` and instead use:

```
for (const i in arrayOfNumbersIHave) {
  if (arrayOfNumbersIHave[i] in snapObject) {
    objToDisplay[arrayOfNumbersIHave[i]] = snapObject[arrayOfNumbersIHave[i]]
  }
}
```

And as @adiga points out below, we can simplify this with a [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop, to get:

```
for (const val of arrayOfNumbersIHave) {
  if (val in snapObject) {
    objToDisplay[val] = snapObject[val];
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't really need the `.toString()` here.

Comment: If you do `i of arrayOfNumbersIHave`, you can simply use `objToDisplay[i]`

Answer (score 3):

You need to check the value of the array, if this is in the object, not by taking an index and look if the index is in an array.

This line

```
if (arrayOfNumbersIHave[i] in snapObject) {
```

takes the value of `arrayOfNumbersIHave[i]` as key for checking with [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) and an object.

```js
var arrayOfNumbersIHave = ["542009988", "7411111111", "542261111", "542009988", "7411111111", "7411111111", "7442334675", "661766029", "692549335"],
    snapObject = { 542009988: "A", 542261111: "B", 661766029: "C", 6617666029: "D", 692549335: "E", 7442334675: "F", 7411111111: "G" },
    objToDisplay = {};

for (const i in arrayOfNumbersIHave) {
    if (arrayOfNumbersIHave[i] in snapObject) {
        objToDisplay[arrayOfNumbersIHave[i]] = snapObject[arrayOfNumbersIHave[i]];
    }
}

console.log(objToDisplay);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply iterate on first array, and check if the current item has any presence in `snapObject`, if so, just create an entry (key) in your `objToDisplay` and assign matched value:

```
arrayOfNumbersIHave.forEach(function(number) {
  if (snapObject[number]) objToDisplay[number] = snapObject[number];
});
```